# Magento Geolocalization/FPC

Tags: magento, geolocation, magento-fpc

In Magento EE I need to redirect customers depending Origin country, browser lang and previous preference set in a cookie.

I have huge problems making it work with FPC.

I tryed to observe the `controller_action_predispatch` event, but FPC somehow caches my redirect instruction and customer is not redirected.

I then tried another solution: extending the run() method in `Mage_Core_Model_App` in order to perform operations before FPC starts to work.

Unfortunately, I don't know why, inside this method you can't access `Mage::getModel()`, `Mage::helper()`, `Mage::getConfig()` ecc

Can you help me please?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I've recently been through exactly the same pain.  You are on the right track;

```
controller_action_predispatch
```

Is the correct event to observe, and you can use this quite happily if you are redirecting to a category or product page with FPC enabled.  The problem is the home page - which is a cms page.  The cms page cache does not fire controller_action_predispatch.  I got around this by adding this to my observer;

```
public function switchUser($event)
{

// CMS page bug, disable FPC to still use observer
    $action = $event->getEvent()->getControllerAction();
    if($action instanceof Mage_Cms_IndexController) {
         $cache = Mage::app()->getCacheInstance();
         $cache->banUse('full_page');
     }
// do the rest of your code here
}
```

The blocks within the cms page will still cache so the page is still nippy, though obviously not as fast as it would be with full FPC enabled.  Its a sound trade off in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you so much PixieMedia. The problem I encounter observing tha event is that, if a redirect is needed, the redirect instruction is not executed my Magento.

I used header('Location: domain') and also Magento setRedirect but no luck

Comment: try: Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);

Comment: Still not working. I debugged a little deeper, when a page is served by the FPC the only events triggered are http_response_send_before and http_response_send_after but observer is not executed

Comment: what version of Magento EE are you using?  this 100% works fine in EE 1.14.1

Comment: could be your other code isnt working correctly, try sticking Mage::log('FIRED',null,'events.log'); in the observer function, clear all caches - including opcache if that is on the server, and nginx if you are using that with sendfile switched on, and go hit the site multiple times. the /var/log/events.log should keep growing

Comment: Thank you for your support PixieMedia. I solved placing a Block before the header.

The block is never cached and it works.

Comment: no problem, im still confused as to why my solution didnt work for you as it works perfectly on the EE site we've just finished.  Anyway, glad you found a solution